# chrome.storage.sync not syncing between browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension in which I would like some data to be synced across multiple computers. I was under the impression that if I was 'signed in' using the same gmail account to two separate chrome browsers (one in a virtual machine running on the same computer) that I should be able to use the chrome.storage.sync.set on one browser, and then retrieve that same data from the other using chrome.storage.sync.get?

I can retrieve the data using the get method from that same browser I ran the set method with (even from a separate incognito window), but the same get command on the other virtual machine returns an empty object.

Both browsers have the 'sync everything' option set in 'advanced sync settings'.
Both browsers have the same chrome version: 33.0.1750.117 m.

Here is my code for setting and getting:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'foo': 'bar'}, function() {});

chrome.storage.sync.get('foo', function(items) {
    console.dir(items);
});
```

Comment: Are both extensions using the same extension ID?

Comment: To build a bit on @abraham's comment (which is very likely the right answer), the extension ID is assigned permanently when you upload to the store. For unpacked extensions in development, the ID is synthesized from a few likely-to-be-sort-of-unusual system variables, such as the directory location of the unpacked extension.   Ask a separate question if you want to know how to make the ID stable while in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @abraham and @sowbug both alluded to, the problem was that when loading unpacked extensions they get assigned different extension ids.
I found the solution here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging#upload
It involves packing the extension from the extensions page in chrome, and then loading the resulting .crx file. Every time this .crx file is loaded it will have the same extension id.